# Data transformation based on the combination of numbers of subjects

Tags: r

I have a big dataset and want to transform it based on the combination of numbers of subjects. Here is a simplified sample dataframe:

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("
group subject status v1 v2
    1       1      1  4 21
    1       2      0  7 10
    1       3      1  3  9
2       1      0  8 75
2       2      1  5  7
2       3      1  2 11
2       4      1  6  1
3       1      1  9 37"), header = TRUE)
```

In the first group, there are three subjects with the first and third ones having status = 1. The combinations of two possible subjects with status = 1 from three subjects are {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}. The new data for the first group looks like this after transformed:

```
newgroup newsubject newstatus newv1 newv2
       1          1         0    11    31
       1          2         1     7    30
       1          3         0    10    19
```

where only the second new subject takes 1 at newstatus because it is transformed from the first and third subjects they both take 1 at status in the original data. newv1 and newv2 are transformed from the summation of `v1` and `v2`: `v1_1 + v1_2 = 4 + 7 = 11, v1_1 + v1_3 = 4 + 3 = 7,  v1_2 + v1_3 = 7 + 3 = 10 ……`

In the fourth group, there are four subjects with the second to fourth ones having status = 1. The combinations of three possible subjects with `status = 1` from four subjects are {(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)}. The new data for the second group looks like this after transformed:

```
newgroup newsubject newstatus newv1 newv2
       2          1         0    15    93
       2          2         0    19    83
       2          3         0    16    87
       2          4         1    13    19
```

The new data for the three groups looks like this:

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("
newgroup newsubject newstatus newv1 newv2
       1          1         0    11    31
       1          2         1     7    30
       1          3         0    10    19
       2          1         0    15    93
       2          2         0    19    83
       2          3         0    16    87
       2          4         1    13    19
       3          1         1     9    37"), header = TRUE)
```

Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: sorry if I'm being dense, but your explanation of the `newstatus` column isn't clear to me.

Comment: Thanks. newstatus is created based on the combination of numbers of subjects. For example, the combinations for the 1st group is {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}, and both the 1st and 3rd (1, 3) subjects take 1s at status in the original data, so the second newsubject takes 1 at newstatus. The 1st and 2nd (1, 2) or the 2nd and 3rd (2, 3) subjects do not both take 1s at status in the original data, so the first and third newsubjects take 0s at newstatus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
# first define the function we will apply to each group
f <- function(group) {
    if (nrow(group) == 1 | sum(group$status) == 0) 
        group
    else 
        with(group, {
                v1 = combn(v1, sum(status), sum)
                v2 = combn(v2, sum(status), sum)
                status = ifelse(combn(status, sum(status), sum) == sum(status), 1, 0)
                subject = seq_along(v1)
                group = rep(group, length.out=length(v1))
                data.frame(group, subject, status, v1, v2)
        })
}

# apply f using by and collapse the results into a data.frame
do.call(rbind, by(data, INDICES=data$group, f))

#     group subject status v1 v2
# 1.1     1       1      0 11 31
# 1.2     1       2      1  7 30
# 1.3     1       3      0 10 19
# 2.4     2       1      0 15 93
# 2.5     2       2      0 19 83
# 2.6     2       3      0 16 87
# 2.7     2       4      1 13 19
# 3       3       1      1  9 37
```

Comment: Very nice. I always forget that `combn` can take a function as an argument. +1.

Comment: Hi mplourde, thanks again for your help. Since I have more than sixty variables in my data, not only v1 and v2, do you have any further idea to deal with it efficiently? Thanks.

Comment: Hi mplourde, I have another question. If I change the status of the third subject in the second group from 1 to 0 (the corresponding combination is {(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)}), it seems the code doesn’t work for it. 

data <- read.table(textConnection("
group subject status v1 v2
    1       1      1  4 21
    1       2      0  7 10
    1       3      1  3  9
    2       1      0  8 75
    2       2      1  5  7
    2       3      0  2 11
    2       4      1  6  1
    3       1      1  9 37"), header = TRUE)

Comment: @user187454 There aren't a lot of options jumping out at me to make this faster. However, if this gets the result you question requested, please remember to accept it.